# Run couchdb.bat in background/no terminal on windows?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, couchdb

I got really excited when I realized that there is finally a GOOD windows installer for couchdb. But I'm not excited that the server doesn't run as a service. You are provided with a .bat file that starts up the couch server, but it requires the terminal stay open.

If I have to, I will just write a windows service that executes the commands in the .bat file, but I would like to know if there is any way to just hide the terminal or run as a background job like you can in Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Caveat: I haven't any first-hand experience with Windows 7.

Does the [srvany](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) utility run under Windows 7?  I've used it to create services for programs that aren't installed as a service.  You could supply the couchdb command-line from the couchdb.bat file as the service path, giving it the command-line parameters that you expect the service to use.

EDIT: I converted the Windows Write-based documentation to PDF and made it [available here](https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B9LOLPyljc8QMjg0M2JmOGEtNWVmZS00ZTZlLWI3MTItNDZhNjhmZmZmMjkw&hl=en_GB), if you would like to see the full guide for `srvany`'s usage.  I'm pretty sure this will do what you need, if it's available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try another batch file!

`Start /B baseball.bat` should start the batch file in the background.